# The funding goal has not been reached?

Tags: solidity, ether, remix

> The previous question remained unanswered, which is why I am asking
>   again !

Whether I will be able to withdraw the funds if the funding goal has been **NOT**
reached, BY TRIGGERING this functions;

```
function ownerSafeWithdrawal() external onlyOwner  {
        uint balanceToSend = address(this).balance;
        beneficiary.transfer(balanceToSend);
        emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, balanceToSend, false);
    }

function checkFundingGoal() internal {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal) {
                fundingGoalReached = true;
                emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
            }
        }
    }
```

My contract is here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xbe1121b96da695cbe68cf8e41f2fba6ea9eb80e9#code

Thank You Robert

Comment: Re-posting your question for more visibility is ill advised. If you would award a bounty on your question, you could get the visibility you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to me like `fundingGoalReached` is not at all linked to `ownerSafeWithdrawal`. So yes, you should be able to withdraw the funds by triggering the function.